# Can Mathematica draw networks with nodes having multiple layers?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, drawing

Some example networks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it will take some hacking with VertexShapeFunction and EdgeShapeFunction and some information encoding in the specification of  the nodes. Do you have a full specification of node types and connection rules?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries basically, each rectangle represents a molecule say a protein. The circles inside are reaction points. Green arrows means protein can switch between different states. The problem is green arrows is on rectangles and black line and the other two type arrows are between circles.

Comment: That's all doable. My question was more about connection logic. Do red and blue always point to purple, and black to black? What kind of nodes are possible? 1, 2, 3 circles in a green box as shown or are there more possibilities? Black and purple always in an oval and blue in a square? Please be specific as it may determine what is possible and how it needs to be specified. Additionally, do you want to use graph algorithms further on or do you simply want a pretty picture?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries red and blue always point to purple ones, but black lines can connect any circles. The top and bottom oval are fixed. In the middle there are only boxes with green or grey. Green on has a green switching arrows. Grey one doesn't. (Ideally, any two or more boxes can be stick to each other, but this might make it too difficult.) if graph algorithms can be applied will be much much greater (still, I think this makes it even harder). Thanks.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries In the middle boxes, they one or more circles. The colour of circles can be black, red, blue, purple.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries If it's too difficult to apply graph algorithm. Then just drawing the graph from code will be much helpful also.

Comment: If the connections are not deterministic, using graphs will be hard. If it's just about drawing you should be able to do this yourself with `Graphics` and its multitude of graphics primitives. You'll need `Circle`, `Line`, `Rectangle`, `FaceForm`, `EdgeForm`, `Arrow`, `BezierCurve`/`BSplineCurve`. Try that, and come back if it doesn't work.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries thanks very much!!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Hi, still have no clue how to build the layer. I can have graph with circles, how can I put some of those circles in a rectangle?

Comment: Draw the rectangle, then at the same location the circles. Later drawings go over earlier ones.